# Washing machine hot water leaking. Is it ok to use with the hot water shut off?

Tags: washing-machine

My washer leaks when I use the hot water. I use cold water for both the wash and rinse cycles. I turned the hot water off at the faucet. This prevents the water from leaking out the water hose in the back. Can I safely use it this way? Or, is there a bigger problem that I haven't noticed yet? The machine is a Kenmore top loader and is approx. 15 years old. Thank you in advance.

Comment: the washer leaks, or the hose leaks? Hoses are easily replaced if that's the issue. But, in general, you don't actually need to use hot water very often with laundry.

Comment: As long as you set the washer to just use cold water, this should work fine. I have a washer at home that will detect lack of pressure on an input and show an error code, but only if the washer tries to draw water out of that line.

Comment: Just make it stop leaking

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to wash without hot water. Just set the setting on the machine for cold wash so it doesn't try an use hot water.

Comment: Some washers have a Cold setting that is slightly tempered with Hot, and a pure Cold.

Comment: Is it a problem to have the washer calling for either hot or cold, and, I assume, powering a solenoid to do so, if the the relevant water supply is turned off?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both hoses are the same age, you should probably inspect/replace the cold water hose. It would be a shame to come home to a flooded house because the cold water side failed while you were not home.